Windows could not find my NVIDIA GPU
I’m having an issue with my laptop’s graphics card. My PC only detects the AMD graphics chip and not my Nvidia graphics card. I’ve tried everything: updating the BIOS, updating Windows, reinstalling Windows. I also went to Device Manager and displayed hidden devices, but nothing worked.
I installed Linux to see if it would detect the card, and it’s visible and usable there, but it’s still not showing up on Windows. Do you have any suggestions? I’ve been trying to fix this for two days, and I’m starting to lose hope.
My graphic card is a RTX 3060 for laptops.

Did you uninstall the AMD drivers?

Yes I did it with https://www.amd.com/en/resources/support-articles/faqs/GPU-601.html but it still doesn't work.

I have also tried to list all pci devices, but the gpu is not listed

I’m voting to close this question because its has been resolved, it doesn't need more answers and is not likely to help future visitors.

Ok found the issue, the GPU wasn’t powered on. To resolve this, I used this tool https://github.com/seerge/g-helper
As shown in this image I was able to adjust the GPU power mode to turn it on.
